# How can we integrate HTML Help files with Table Of Contents into an application developing in C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

How can we integrate HTML Help files with Table Of Contents into an application developing in C#.NET.

While installing the application (.exe), the help files also should get extracted into the installation folder and when the user press F1 key or click on the Help Icon/ link, the index.htm page should display in a browser.

Please note that the html files are having CSS, Images, and Scripts in separate folders.

Kind regards,
Adarsh

Comment: The files can be added in as content in the installer. Visual Studio provides integration with Install Shield. The binding with F1 can be done using event handlers in your application. I'd recommend you create an install application first.

Answer (score 2):

> Please note that the html files are having CSS, Images, and Scripts in separate folders.

HTML Help uses a `.chm` file, the HelpProvider class helps you use it.  If you still only have raw .htm files then you forgot to build the .chm file.  Use the [HTML Help Workshop](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21138) utility.

Do note that this tool is end-of-life, just about everybody switched to displaying help in a browser by having it visit a web site you maintain.  There is otherwise no dedicated support for this in the .NET Framework beyond the Process.Start() method.

Comment: Hi Hans, Thank you for your clarifications. I have compiled htm files into a chm file. Could you please provide me a step-by-step instruction so that the chm file opens when the user press F1 or click on the help icon. Thank you!

Comment: MSDN already shows you how to use the HelpProvider class.  Click the Ask Question button if something is unclear about it.  Be specific.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must integrate in your setup the help files. Then you can take a look to [HelpProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.helpprovider.aspx). For running the `index.html` you can simply use: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("filename.html");`